# Is it possible to use dagger at android project unit testing?

Tags: android, unit-testing, dagger-2, robolectric

I want to use Dagger + Robolectric in src/test/java package. Is it possible? How?
Somebody wrote their Robolectric tests at src/androidTest/java package then used Dagger, But Robolectric is a framework that runs your tests inside the JVM on your workstation in seconds.
If I write my test in src/androidTest/java package it won't run inside the JVM.

Anyway, Is it right to use Dagger at src/test/java package? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's perfectly possible to use dagger in robolectric tests. But in general

> You don’t have to use Dagger for single-class unit tests

https://google.github.io/dagger/testing.html

Comment: Yes thats true. How about Integration Tests? I want to write Integration Tests with Robolectric. So this isn't single-class test. How I can use dagger it in my test under src/test/java package?

Comment: Use Option 2: Separate component configurations